# Entity Framework SaveChanges returns nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone advise on this error below?

After this error occurs, any changes made in this web application are not saved to the database.

Also strange moment, this error appears only in production environment

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<GetStateEntries>b__19(ObjectStateEntry e)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Impl.UnitOfWork.Rollback() in C:\_projects\SomeProjectName\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.EntityFramework\Impl\UnitOfWork.cs:line 23
  at Web.Application.FormControllerBase.Form[TForm](TForm form) in C:\_projects\SomeProjectName\Web.Application\FormControllerBase.cs:line 57
  at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

UnitOfWork.cs:line 23

```
_context.SaveChanges()
```

Context class:

```
{
    public class SomeModel : DbContext
    {
        public SomeModel() : base("name=Main")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SomeModel>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
        //other DbSets

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new ColumnNameUpperCaseConvention());
            modelBuilder.Types().Configure(x => x.ToTable(NameConventions.GetTableName(x.ClrType)));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Roles)
                .WithMany(x => x.Admins)
                .Map(x => x.ToTable("ADMIN_ROLE"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<LeaveRequest>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.ScheduleRequest)
                .WithOptionalDependent()
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("SCHEDULE_REQUEST_ID"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduleRequest>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.LeaveRequest)
                .WithOptionalDependent()
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("LEAVE_REQUEST_ID"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("__APPLICATION_USER");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(x => x.Nk);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your `DbContext` class

Comment: Why are you setting the initializer to null? That line isn't required.

Comment: it's required to disable code first :)

Comment: I believe in yourr `Select` clause, you are trying to access a property of object which is null. You can check why it's not populated if it was supposed to populate or handle it using null check condition.

Comment: "UnitOfWork.cs:line 23, _context.SaveChanges()" If this is all the failing code we're going to see there's not much we can do.